# Android Nullpointerexception thrown when R.id value not found

Tags: android, ant, r.java-file

When I add a new activity (.java and .XML files) in my Android Project some R.id values that used to work get lost and causes my App to throw a NullPointerException, but if I use the hex value it works again:

```
R.java: public static final int editTextTotal=0x7f040064;

findViewById(R.id.editTextTotal); //Throws nullpointerex after I add a new activity.

findViewById(0x7f040067) //Works
```

I got tired of Eclipse so I'm working with commands only, is there anything else that should be done other than add the files, change the manifest and run the "ant debug" command to add new activities?

Comment: If you use latest sdk, then have you tried doing `Build->Rebuild Project` whenever you get the error?

Comment: Add your XMl code , i think there is some errors in your new xml file

Comment: please post error log or some snippet.

Answer (score 0):

What is the import your are using? You have to use

> your_package_name.R

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your ADT. Try to update to the latest version.

If the problem still exists, try to clean the project whenever you add a new xml.